# How to create session for each Tab in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create session for each tab in jQuery?

In my application, I have two tabs. If I create a first tab dynamically, a tab will create and some content will load.  Then if I create next tab, the content of second loading properly.  But again I go to first tab, the contents are not loaded fully.

It stopped while I created second tab.  Only remaining contents are displayed.  Please help me.

Comment: we might read it fully, but your explanation, without any code, does not give sufficient information

Comment: What do you mean exactly with a session?

Comment: Simply I want to create like browser tabs...At a same time i want to create multiple tabs and it is loading contents independently.....

Answer (score 2):

Place an iFrame in every tab page. The result will be that a new session is created for every tabbed page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
loadtab1() {
    if(loaded(this)) {
       return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

loadtab2() {
    if(loadtab1()) { load(this) }
}
```